# Converting list to dictionary, and tokenizing the key values - possible?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, nltk

So basically I have a folder of files I'm opening and reading into python.

I want to search these files and count the keywords in each file, to make a dataframe like the attached image.

[image]
I have managed to open and read these files into a list, but my problem is as follows:

**Edit 1:**

I decided to try and import the files as a dictionary instead. It works, but when I try to lower-case the values, I get a 'list' object attribute error - even though in my variable explorer, it's defined as a dictionary.

```
import os
filenames = os.listdir('.')
file_dict = {}
for file in filenames:
    with open(file) as f:
        items = [i.strip() for i in f.read().split(",")]
    file_dict[file.replace(".txt", "")] = items

def lower_dict(d):
   new_dict = dict((k, v.lower()) for k, v in d.items())
   return new_dict
print(lower_dict(file_dict))
```

output =

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

**Pre-edit post:**

**1.** Each list value doesn't retain the filename key. So I don't have the rows I need.

**2.** I can't conduct a search of keywords in the list anyway, because it is not tokenized. So I can't count the keywords per file.

Here's my code for opening the files, converting them to lowercase and storing them in a list.

**How can I transform this into a dictionary retaining the filename, and tokenized key values?**. Additionally, is it better to somehow import the file and contents into a dictionary directly? Can I still tokenize and lower-case everything?

```
import os
import nltk
# create list of filenames to loop over
filenames = os.listdir('.')
#create an empty list for storage 
Lcase_content = []
tokenized = []
num = 0
# read files from folder, convert to lower case 
for filename in filenames:  
    if filename.endswith(".txt"): 
        with open(os.path.join('.', filename)) as file: 
            content = file.read()   
            # convert to lower-case value 
            Lcase_content.append(content.lower())

       ## this two lines below don't work - index out of range error
            tokenized[num] = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(tokenized[num])
            num = num + 1
```

Comment: It sounds like a data structure problem. I’d suggest looking in the `collections` module that comes with python. You might be able to find something you are looking for.

Comment: `counter ` in collections can have it's keys counted - I know I'd have to use that, but tokenizing part is giving me grief

Comment: What is tokenizing?

Comment: splitting strings like "This is a string" into separate strings like "this", "is", "a", "string" so that I can run searches through it

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the count of each token by using Collections. `collections.Counter` can take a list of strings and return a dictionary-like Counter with each token in its keys and the count of the tokens in values. Since NLTK's `workd_tokenize` takes a sequence of strings and returns a list, to get a dictionary with tokens and their counts, you can basically do this:

`Counter(nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize())`

Since you want your file names as index (first column), make it as a nested dictionary, with a file name as a key and another dictionary with tokens and counts as a value, which looks like this:

{'file1.txt': Counter({'cat': 4, 'dog': 0, 'squirrel': 12, 'sea horse': 3}),
 'file2.txt': Counter({'cat': 11, 'dog': 4, 'squirrel': 17, 'sea horse': 0})}

If you are familiar with Pandas, you can convert your dictionary to a Pandas dataframe. It will make your life so much easier to work with any tsv/csv/excel file by exporting the Pandas dataframe result as a csv file. Make sure you apply `.lower()` to your file content and include `orient='index'` so that files names be your index.

```
import os
import nltk
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

result = dict()

filenames = os.listdir('.')
for filename in filenames:
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        with open(os.path.join('.', filename)) as file:
            content = file.read().lower()
            result[filename] = Counter(nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(content))

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result, orient='index').fillna(0)

df['total words'] = df.sum(axis=1)

df.to_csv('words_count.csv', index=True)
```

Re: your first attempt, since your 'items' is a list (see `[i.strip() for i in f.read().split(",")]`), you can't apply `.lower()` to it.

Re: your second attempt, your 'tokenized' is empty as it was initialized as `tokenized = []`. That's why when you try to do `tokenized[num] = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(tokenized[num])`, `tokenized[num]` with num = 0 gives you the index out of range error.